# the output of answer is repeating

Tags: python

I am getting repeated list, can any one correct my code not to repeat the list

```
date=['Oct-2017', 'Dec-2016', 'Nov-2016', 'Oct-2016', 'Mar-19', 'Feb-19',
           'Jan-19', 'Jun-19', 'May-19', 'Apr-19', 'Sep-19', 'Aug-19',
           'Jul-19']
    df=pd.Series(date)
    lst=['Mar-19', 'Feb-19','Jan-19', 'Jun-19', 'May-19', 'Apr-19', 'Sep-19', 'Aug-19','Jul-19']
    b=[]
    def impute_val(df,lst):
        for i in range(len(df)):
            for j in lst:
                if df[i]==j:
                    a=df[i]
                    if a is not str:
                        a=str(a)
                        a=a.split('-')
                        if a[1]=='19':
                            c=a[0]+'-2019'
                            b.append(c)
                else:
                    b.append(df[i])
```

Comment: Convert to `set`

Comment: Your code works fine. what is your need . can you explain what do you want to do?

Comment: in my output wrong format code is also repeating example Sep-2019',
 'Sep-19',
 'Sep-19',
 'Aug-19',
 'Aug-19',
 'Aug-19',
 'Aug-19',
 'Aug-19',
 'Aug-19',
 'Aug-19',
 'Aug-2019',
 'Aug-19',

Comment: are you trying to convert all 2019 to 19 and 2020 to 20?

Comment: am trying to convert 19 to 2019

Comment: did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: Please include *the output you're expecting* and *the output you're getting*.

Answer (score 0):

change your code you are iterating over all item instead check if the item is in list or not

```
date=['Oct-2017', 'Dec-2016', 'Nov-2016', 'Oct-2016', 'Mar-19', 'Feb-19',
           'Jan-19', 'Jun-19', 'May-19', 'Apr-19', 'Sep-19', 'Aug-19',
           'Jul-19']
df=pd.Series(date)
lst=['Mar-19', 'Feb-19','Jan-19', 'Jun-19', 'May-19', 'Apr-19', 'Sep-19', 'Aug-19','Jul-19']
b=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df[i] in lst:
        a=df[i]
        if a is not str:
            a=str(a)
            a=a.split('-')
            if a[1]=='19':
                c=a[0]+'-2019'
                b.append(c)
    else:
        b.append(df[i])
```

And if you only want to change 19 to 2019 you dont need such long code you can do it with simple lambda on pandas series using apply function:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.where(len(x.split('-')[1])==2, x.split('-')[0]+'-20'+x.split('-')[1],x))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all  `if a is not str:` never working because `a` is always `str` and btw this syntax is wrong you have to use `isinstance(var, str)` for checking is somth string or not, and your programm only goes into `else: b.append(df[i])`.

And the problem for `b` is , You are using `nested for` ( `for` in `for`) :

```
for i in range(len(df)):
        for j in lst:
```

that means : for each `i` your program do `b.append(df[i])` (since your program only goes into `else: b.append(df[i])` )  `j` times and that is equal to `13*9` times `b.append(df[i])` called , So that's why you see repeated things in `b` after program ran.

Comment: Iam excepting output as below, but am not getting
['Oct-2017', 'Dec-2016', 'Nov-2016', 'Oct-2016', 'Mar-2019', 'Feb-2019',
'Jan-2019', 'Jun-2019', 'May-2019', 'Apr-2019', 'Sep-2019', 'Aug-2019',
'Jul-2019']

Comment: Actually, `a` will *never* be `str` in the example shown. `str` is a class; a given string is not that class, it's an instance *of* that class. If for some reason you want to check if `a` isn't a string, you would use `not isinstance(a, str)`.

Comment: @shiva kumar if that's the output you're expecting, what is `lst` for? That's just all the entries in `date`, with the years converted to four digits. I'm not even sure why you're using `pandas`.